# Safe changed image in same screen size and show as maximized splash screen

Tags: matlab

Hi I have a question about following code:

```
im = imread('image1.png');
f = figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1],'visible','off'); imshow(im, 'Border', 'tight');
rectangle('Position', [100, 100, 10, 10]);
print(f, '-r0', '-dtiff', 'image2.tif');
splash('image2','tif',3000);
```

I want that Matlab is:

1) Reading an Image

2) Showing one or more rectangle on that image

3) Safe that image (up to this step Matlab is doing what it should

4) Open it in the same size like the first image from 1)

5) Showing the new Image as splash screen all over the screen(just image nothing more)

My problem is that the saved image from matlab (point 3)) is always to small (Matlab is giving it a smaller size). So that the splash screen is not all over the screen.

Thanks guys and cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-r0` means "screen resolution", it doesn't control the size of the output image.  Straight from the docs, under the heading **Printing Figures at Screen Size**, you need to do this before `print`:

```
set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto')
```

Comment: cheers mate! I just started programming with Matlab great help!